# bootstrap jquery load sequence

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this line of code in a page to trigger a modal:

```
<?php if($modal_show){?>
<script>$('#modalContactForm').modal('show');</script>
<?php } ?>
```

the loads of jQuery etc are at the end of the script before the , as is the recommended method.  For testing $modal_show is set to true upon page load.  If I move the loads up to the top the modal is shown as anticipated, but when they are at the end it is not shown.  I have read other solutions, using a javascript window onload or using defer statement.  Can someone show me the actual code I need to put in there to keep the loads at the end and have the script trigger the modal.

Comment: The problem here is that php is executed server side , while javascript are on client side, so php tries to execute the script which is not yet loaded.

Comment: Yes this makes total sense, but it seems like there should be some easy way around it as twitter bootstrap recommends doing the loads at the end of the page.  Don't see how that can normally work as you would need to use it within the page.

Comment: Why dont you load the php script at the very end of the page just above closing body tag, below the script?

Comment: Lets say I am executing a php script while in the footer (for example) and then I want to show to modal right there within that php block.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can put the modal where ever you want. The id will play the keyrole, i have a project with multiple modal, being loaded by script as and when required. So it should work. Just call the modal id

Comment: OK, that clarifies it... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the jquery/bootstrap-jquery library first then your script in order for your script to work.

You can use [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> //LOAD THE LIBRARY FIRST
 <script> //THEN YOUR SCRIPT
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#modalContactForm').modal('show');
 }); // TRIGGERS UPON THE PAGE IS COMPLETELY LOADED
 </script>
```

Or the shorthand

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
    $('#modalContactForm').modal('show');
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Is there any way around loading the jquery first?  I could just load the jquery at the top of the script but bootstrap recommends having it at the bottom.  In some cases I will need to trigger the modals in-line prior t the end of the page.

Comment: Note Vipin comments under the question.